# random space at edges while using "justify-content: space-between"?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#left,
#right {
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <span id="left"></span>
  <span id="topic">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span>
  <span id="right"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: don't set auto when you rest the margin

Answer (score 0):

Try setting all the default margins explicitly to 0. The margin of the body might be affecting your layout.

```
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing:  border-box;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#header {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: grey;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
}

#left,
#right {
  margin: 0; /* Reset the margin set in the first rule */
  
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <span id="left"></span>
  <span id="topic">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span>
  <span id="right"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: This worked as well !! Tysmm !